# Getting different values for order of filter using Chebyshev method-:

Tags: filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

Here are the 2 solutions. I am getting 2 different values of order of filter for the given question. Which is wrong and which is right? Or are both right? Please guide

[image]

$|H(j\Omega)|=-20\log_{10}\epsilon-6(N-1)-20N\log_{10}\Omega_s$

Comment: Could you please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? The last two lines are not very clear (neither is the rest, but it's legible, somehow). At any rate, the 1st formula is the correct one; I can't say anything about the 2nd one.

Comment: I edited the question @aconcernedcitizen It is more clear now. I think.

Comment: I personally think second formula is right(just guessing by the book that I am following). But one of my teacher taught me first formula, whereas another teacher taught me second formula, I am confused.

Comment: I still can't understand: is that $\varepsilon-6CN-D$, or $\varepsilon-6(N-1)$? I would lean towards the second, but I don't know where you got that 6 and N-1 from. Can you show a reference where you got that formula?

Comment: I edited the question in the main question itself(in mathjax). I think now it is understandable. I don't have the derivation as well.

Comment: You said it's from a book, and that another teacher taught you that formula. Can't you post at least one of the two? I admit I'm very curious, because not only that $|H(j\Omega)|$ is mysterious ($\Omega$ being a variable), but that $6(N-1)$ is even more mysterious: where did it come from? Otherwise your second formula is plain wrong if it doesn't give an answer exactly the same as the first (established) one. What made you think that it's a good formula?